# Multiple web controls to trigger one Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have three web controls that has to update a gridview inside an updatepanel.

The markup is like this:

```
<asp:DropDown></asp:DropDown>
<asp:Button></asp:Button>
<asp:DropDown></asp:DropDown>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Gridview></asp:Gridview>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I cannot put the updatepanel before the first dropdown because I have used the bootstrap datepicker and that does not behave properly if I put the updatepanel in the start.

Comment: take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864692/how-to-update-a-control-outside-of-an-updatepanel

Comment: for bootstrap problem you can place your datepicker code within function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {}}

Comment: The datepicker is a custom control and the code for it is written in that custom control.

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to all this.

Comment: Amit Mishra thank you so much for the link you provided. :)