# Repeater Not Updating After Databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding

I have a page and there is a repeater on it. On `Button(btnExport)` click I export data to Excel, so I add button in `UpdatePanel` an set `PostBackTrigger`.

I have `method(BindData)` that `databinding` a repeater. So my problem is that when I adding `BindData` method in `Button click(btnExport_click)` the repeater not refreshing(PS: `Dataset` returns new values that updated and `DataBind()` method works, but repeater not refreshing).This is my first post, sorry if the question is not completely clear. Thanks advance.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGoods" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litGoodCode" runat="server" Text='<%# 
        Eval("GOODS_CODE") %>' />
        <asp:Literal ID="litGoodName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
       Eval("GOODS_CNAME") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upd_Export" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void btnExport_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportToExcel();
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    try
    {

        rptGoods.DataSource = /Here I  get Dataset/
        rptGoods.DataBind();                 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHelper exsaver = new ExceptionHelper();
        exsaver.SaveException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Repeater located outside of the UpdatePanel? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864692/how-to-update-a-control-outside-of-an-updatepanel

Comment: You cannot export a file AND update the UI. It's one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think problem in PostBackTrigger

Comment: No, the problem is exactly what VDWWD said it was. You can do one or the other, not both in the same response. If you want the user to download a file, open a separate tab/window just for the download.

Comment: You're right. Export must on separate tab. Thank you All

Answer (score 1):

Since the Repeater is placed outside the UpdatePanel, it won't be refreshed after an asynchronous postback. Only the UpdatePanel's content is refreshed.

Move the Repeater inside the UpdatePanel or wrap it by another UpdatePanel.